# Cannot ungroup a PowerPoint SmartArt Shape

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

I try to ungroup a SmartArt shape from code, but it always causes an error: "This member can only be accessed for a group".

However, it's working, if I right click on the SmartArt shape, and ungroup it.

How can I fix this?

My code is:

```
public void CreateSmartArt(PowerPoint.Shapes allShapes)

{

     PowerPoint.Shape smartartShape = allShapes.AddSmartArt(IttPowerPoint.Instance.PowerPointApp.SmartArtLayouts["MyLayOut"], 0f, 0f, width, height);

     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(smartartShape); smartartShape = null;

}



Public void UngroupSmartArt(PowerPoint.Shape shape)

{

     try

     {

            shape.Ungroup();

     }

     catch (Exception ex)

     {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

     }
}
```

Note: I am using VS Ultimate 2013, PowerPoint2013, C#

Comment: You can only ungroup a shape group not the shapes that make up the group. You need to find the correct shape to pass to your function.

Comment: Ok, so my question is how to ungroup a smartart shape programmatically? We can ungroup a smartart shape by right clicking on it and then group->ungroup. How can we make it from code?

Comment: You'll have to find the group shape.  Loop through all of the shapes until you find one of the group type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you'd do it like so, asssuming a reference to the smartart shape in osh:

```
osh.Copy
osh.Delete
Set osh = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)
With osh.Ungroup
    .Ungroup
End With
```

Copy the SmartArt shape to the clipboard
Delete it from the slide
Paste it back onto the slide as an Enhanced Metafile
Ungroup it then ungroup the result.

Voila.  Shapes.

You'll want to pick up the top/left coordinates of the Smart Art before copying/deleting it, then apply them to the pasted EMF.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265724(v=office.12).aspx) and [ParentGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265725(v=office.12).aspx) properties of the Shape object. This might solve your problem.

Comment: From your code it doesn't seem like you are trying to do it either. Your UngroupSmartArt method gets a Shape object and not a SmartArt object. And the object that your method gets is not a group, but a regular shape. That's why you get the error that you specified. The API does not allow you to ungroup a standalone shape (like jarker2160 explained). If you have a shape that is a part of the group you can get the parent group via the methods that I proposed. If that is your case then it might help you. If not then please try to explain what exactly is the shape that gets passed to the method.

Comment: If you call UngroupSmartArt(smartartShape); before you release the object, does that work?

Comment: :they are two separate functions which are convenient to use.  All the things you said, I agree. But there is no way to convert (or ungroup) a smartart shape to shapes.