# Powerpoint VBA - Move chldnode of Vertical Block List to the left

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Please check below screenshot & code. It has my questions and code I have written so far (which is failing)

[image]

> Below is my code:

```
Private Sub VerticalBlockList()
    Dim oPPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Const ppLayoutTitleAndContent As Byte = 32

    Set oPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    Set oPres = oPPT.Presentations.Add()

    Dim layout As SmartArtLayout
    Set layout = Application.SmartArtLayouts(26)

    With oPres.Slides.Add(oPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleAndContent)
        With .Shapes.AddSmartArt(layout, 30, 180, 318, 252)
            With .SmartArt
                .Nodes(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Sample-1"
                .Nodes(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Sample-2"

                ' Below statement throws error.
                ' basically I want to move the bullet section to little bit on left so that the bullet points doesn't show up
                ' P.S. there is no way I can remove that bullet in a Vertical Block List

                .Nodes(1).Shapes(2).left = .Nodes(1).Shapes(2).left - 30

            End With
        End With
    End With    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to move the shape, you can just remove the bullets:

```
        .Nodes(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = msoBulletNone
```

Comment: The statement executes file but bullet still remains. You won't be able to remove it manually as well so I though of moving it to little bit on left side.

Comment: When I run your code, replacing the line where you move the shape with the code to remove the bullets, the bullets disappear. The bullets in that SmartArt layout can also be removed manually. If that is not working for you then you have some other issue.

Comment: Which version of PPT are you using?

Comment: I use Office 2013. I will check again at my end

Comment: That may well be the problem. SmartArt has been improved in O365. I don't have a copy of Office 2013 to test but I do recall that object model support for SmartArt was patchy at best. Ungrouping it won't help either as it will turn it into standard shapes. Looks like you'll have to learn to like the bullets!